# Google Plus plugin throws some errors in ionic 1 & 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I added `cordova-plugin-googleplus` to my project. Now I am trying to build android apk but some errors are throwing after adding the googleplus plugin.

```
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:bundleDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary

UP-TO-DATE

:preReleaseBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library

UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4141Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library

UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library

UP-TO-DATE

:prepareDebugDependencies


:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResValues
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugSources
 UP-TO-DATE

:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no p
revious execution, etc.).

C:\xampp\htdocs\IONIC\ionic2\githubIonic\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plug
ins\GooglePlus.java:325: error: cannot find symbol

                result.put("familyName", acct.getFamilyName());

                                             ^

  symbol:   method getFamilyName()


  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount

C:\xampp\htdocs\IONIC\ionic2\githubIonic\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plug
ins\GooglePlus.java:326: error: cannot find symbol

                result.put("givenName", acct.getGivenName());

                                            ^

  symbol:   method getGivenName()

  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount


Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

2 errors

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Try:

Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
 get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.12 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\xampp\htdocs\IONIC\ionic2\githubIonic\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plug
ins\GooglePlus.java:325: error: cannot find symbol
                result.put("familyName", acct.getFamilyName());
                                             ^
  symbol:   method getFamilyName()
  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount
C:\xampp\htdocs\IONIC\ionic2\githubIonic\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plug
ins\GooglePlus.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
                result.put("givenName", acct.getGivenName());
                                            ^
  symbol:   method getGivenName()
  location: variable acct of type GoogleSignInAccount
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

If I remove the plugin, its working fine. What is the problem with the plugin or is there anything other I have to do? Please help as fast as you can.

Comment: Is acct the plugin name? Check if that is the correct way to call the plugin api

Comment: I don't know. It is in the generated java file when I added the plugin. That is not part of my code.

Comment: You can try to update your Android SDK, especially the Play Services repository

Comment: When facing problems with a certain plugin, it will be good to check under issues in github to see if anybody had the same problem OR post your question there so the plugin owner is able to help you directly. Here is a thread with the identical problem: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/278